# Drupal Cache send to a 404 page after a while

Tags: caching

I have a multilingual website which use cache (views cache activated, performance on ...).

That website works well but, sometime, after a while, some homepages in others language are redirecting to a 404 page when we try to watch them unidentified. The homepage in main language still works fine.

So to solve that, i have to flush the cache and all the pages are accessible again.

But i can't each week survey my customer website just to watch if i need to flush the caches. So any idea to solve that definitely.

Thanks!